# Problems with positioning textView under another textView in relative layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to position my textview with numbers under the textview that contains text.
I use this layout and the textviews overlap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/back"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--  we include header  -->
<include
    layout="@layout/header"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/spin" />

    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="Some text to display:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:text="123 456 789"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffcc"/>   

    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

What i get with this is:

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need `android:layout_below="@id/tv1"` in your TextView for numbers

Answer (score 6):

In your second `TextView` add

```
android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using a relative layout, but you're not telling the second TextView what to be positioned relative to. Add this to your second TextView:

```
android:layout_below:"@id/tv1"
```

Comment: Hey, just so you know the notation of "@+id" adds a new ID string to the R.java file. You should omit the "+" character if the TextView already has an id.

Comment: 13 months on, your code is still around and being read by folks like me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using LinearLayout unless as RelativeLayouts are not meant to stacking elements on-top of each other by design, the following code creates a textview under another textview;

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/deal_time_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/deal_item_bg_red_gradient"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="6.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="12.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="6.0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/name"
                style="@style/deal_item_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/deal_details_time_ends" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/company"
                style="@style/deal_item_number"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-1.0dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/deal_details_time_redem"
                android:textSize="12.0dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
```

To the XML of the View which you want to position below.